# Generating query clauses with korma and clojure

Tags: sql, clojure, korma

I am trying to generate korma query conditions based on a map of columns and values that I pass into a function.

I am finding that when an empty map is passed to korma's where:

```
(select "things"
  (where conditions))
```

Generates queries with an empty WHERE which causes a SQL error:

```
SELECT * FROM things WHERE () LIMIT 10
```

However using this form:

```
(select "things"
  (if-not (empty? conditions) 
    (where conditions)))
```

Results in an error: "Wrong number of args (1) passed to: core$where"

Is there an idiomatic way of handling dynamic clauses in korma?

UPDATE

The following works, but is pretty clumsy (note the strangely necessary if format)

```
(defn do-select []
  (->  (select* "things") 
    (fields :id :data)
    (limit 10)))

(defn add-constraints [query conditions]
  (if (empty? conditions) 
      query
      (where query (conditions-to-clause-map conditions))))

(select (do-select) 
  (add-constraints conditions)           
  (where (is_owner? owner)))
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think if it is possible to generate dynamic queries without looking under the hood of korma and trying to call some private API, but that is a bad bad idea. The problem with your second code is that `select` and `where` are macros. What select does is:

```
(defmacro select
    [ent & body]
      `(let [query# (-> (select* ~ent)
                     ~@body)]
         (exec query#)))
```

As you can see it thread the `select*` return value to next forms and if you introduce the `if` clause that causes this threading to break and `where` gets only one value (which was your map) rather than the getting value of select* and the map, hence the error says wrong number of arguments.

As of now it seems `eval` with some dynamic code generation is your friend. Something like:

```
(eval `(select "things"
       ~(if (empty? conditions) 
           `identity
           `(where conditions))))
```

I haven't tried it, but I hope it gives you the idea.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little odd at first but keeping the "code as data" mantra in mind, I created a "my-where" function that would either pass along the original query of no conditions or insert a real korma where clause as the result.

Something like:

```
(defn my-where [query conditions]
  (if-not (nil? conditions)
    (-> query (where conditions))
    query))
```

Then you could use:

```
(select "things"
  (my-where conditions))
```

Hope this helps,
Greg

Answer (score 1):

You've probably figured out a way to solve this but I'll chime in. Personally I end up using the cond-> macro which is available if you're using Clojure 1.6+.

You can find information on the new threading macros [here](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/changes.md#24-new-threading-macros).

The resulting code looks like something like this:

```
(let [query (->(select* "things") 
                 (fields :id :data)
                 (limit 10))]
  (-> (cond-> query
         conditions (where conditions)
         more-conditions (where more-conditions))
      (exec)))
```