# clojure: dynamically compose query with korma

Tags: clojure, korma

I am trying to create a very simple API with [korma](http://sqlkorma.com/)

Users can query a database like so:

```
localhost:8080/my_postgres_db/users.json?where[age]=50&limit=1
```

Currently I am getting an error when trying to apply a where clause to an existing, composable, query.

```
clojure.lang.ArityException: Wrong number of args (2) passed to: core$where
```

**The code in question**:

```
(defn- comp-query [q [func arg]]
  (let [sql-fn (ns-resolve 'korma.core (-> func name symbol))]
    (sql-fn q arg)))

(defn compose-query [table col]
  (reduce comp-query (select* table) col))
```

**Usage**:

```
 (def clauses {:where {:column1 10} :fields "a,b" :limit 10 :offset 500})
 (-> (compose-query table clauses) select)
```

Everything behaves as expected, except for where clauses. I can combine limit, offset and fields in any way I choose and I get the expected results. Only when I have a `:where` key in my map do I run into the error.

Am I attempting something I shouldn't? Is this bad clojure? Any help would be appreciated.

**Note:** I have read this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10961285/generating-query-clauses-with-korma-and-clojure)

**Edit**: from `lein repl` I can manually compose a query in the same fashion and it works

```
(where (select* "my_table") {:a 5})
```

**Edit:**
If I modify my `compose-query` function to this:

```
(defn compose-query [table col]
  ; remove where clause to process seperately
  (let [base (reduce comp-query (select* table) (dissoc col :where))]
    (if-let [where-clause (:where col)]
      (-> base (where where-clause))
      base)))
```

Everything works as expected.

Comment: where to the values of name and symbol come from?

Comment: @ArthurUlfeldt please see my comment to your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that `korma.core/where` is not a function and needs to be handled specially. Where can't be implemented as a function and still correctly handle things like `(where query (or (= :hits 1) (> :hits 5)))`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `where*` function as you are using `select*`.
Just make your clause map like:

```
(def clauses {:where* {:column1 10} :fields "a,b" :limit 10 :offset 500})
```

Comment: I think this could work, it avoided the arity problem but left me with SQL syntax issues. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Just a hunch; expanding some of the threading macros makes it a little hard to see if they are correct:

```
core> (macroexpand-1 '(-> (compose-query table clauses) select))
(select (compose-query table clauses))                                                                     
core> (macroexpand-1 '(-> func name symbol))
(clojure.core/-> (clojure.core/-> func name) symbol)                                                       
core> (macroexpand-1 '(clojure.core/-> func name))
(name func)
```

Passing func to name looks suspicious.

Comment: Thank you for looking at this. `func` is a keyword at that point. An example is `(symbol (name :where))` which gets resolved in the `korma.core` namespace. I'm just looking up a korma function so I can execute it.